# `${fn.sum()}` JSON object yields different decimal value from fn.sum()

Tags: json, object, sum, marklogic

I have two sets of server-side Javascripts:

**1)**

```
const marketValue = []

**************MarkLogic retrieves property value***************

  marketValue.push(mktValue);

}
const isFloored = {'marketValue': fn.sum(marketValue)}
let devilBargain = {rDate, isFloored};
devilsBargain;

 1) Result:

{
 "rDate": "2019-01-18", 
 "isFloored": {
  "marketValue": -36105.95
 }
}
```

**2)**

```
const marketValue = []

**************MarkLogic retrieves property value***************

  marketValue.push(mktValue);

}
const isFloored = `${fn.sum(marketValue)}`;
let devilBargain = {rDate, isFloored};
devilsBargain;

2) Result:

{
 "rDate": "2019-01-18", 
 "isFloored": "-36105.950000000004"
}
```

**1)** yields the correct decimal value -36105.95 but not with the desired format

**2)** yields the wrong decimal value "-36105.950000000004" but with the desired non-nested object format

How can I get the correct decimal value in non-nested JSON object format?

```
{
 "rDate": "2019-01-18", 
 "isFloored": -36105.95
}
```

Comment: Have you tried constructing the JSON in the more traditional way yet, like `devilsBargain = { rDate, isFloored: fn.sum(marketValue)}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating the `isFloored` variable that has an object with the `marketValue` property, why not create as variable that is just the `sum()` of the array of values?

```
'use strict';
const marketValue = []
marketValue.push(-36105.95);
const rDate = "2019-01-18"
const isFloored = fn.sum(marketValue)
let devilsBargain = {rDate, isFloored};
devilsBargain;
```

That yields:

```
{
 "rDate": "2019-01-18", 
 "isFloored": -36105.95
}
```